# key_load_public: No such file or directory even though file exists

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to connect to a Bitbucket server. My machine has Windows, with Git Bash.

On `/h/.ssh/id_rsa` and `/h/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, I have a key for the repository.
Also in `/h/.ssh/config`, I have the configuration for the repository:

```
Host my-repo-name
        User my-user
        Hostname my-repo.com
        Port 7999
        IdentityFile id_rsa
```

When I'm trying to connect to the repository like this:

```
ssh -Tv git@my-repo.com
```

I'm getting this message:

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /h//.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to my-repo.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

There are two things I don't understand here:

1.If I have `/h/.ssh/id_rsa` and  `/h/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, why am I getting `key_load_public: No such file or directory`?

2.If in the configuration I specify `Port 7999`, why does it connect to port 22 `Connecting to my-repo.com port 22`?

Comment: also, keep in mind that this message can come from the server, if your public key has not been properly imported yet

Comment: btw `key_load_public: No such file or directory` message is for **below** line not above. I'm sure there's another line like `identity file /h/.ssh/....` below, msg was meant for that file not `id_rsa` (above line) file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. If I have /h/.ssh/id_rsa and /h/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, why am I getting key_load_public: No such file or directory?

It is just bogus warning. More information can be found if you run with more verbose log level `-vvv`.

> 2. If in the configuration I specify Port 7999, why does it connect to port 22 Connecting to my-repo.com port 22?

Because the `Port 7999` is sepcified only for host `my-repo-name`, not for `my-repo.com` where you are trying to connect. It would get used if you would run

```
ssh -Tv git@my-repo-name
```

Comment: I was getting the same error, even tried it with -vvvv, and I suspect most of it was bogus. The actual reason is that gitlab.com was being blocked by my company firewall. I know this because I was able to ssh to the internal gitlab host. Why the error report didn't just say that is beyond me

Comment: @N.S. I thought that I had been blacklisted on gitlab because of too many pw attempts and public keys. It turned out that it is just a problem of the known hosts, see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried to clone a gitlab project, and the solution should work for any git service. The error was

```
#15 0.589 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1, 
#15 0.589 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

It disappeared after using

```
echo "Host *\n  User git\n  HostName gitlab.com\n  AddKeysToAgent yes\n  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

This is also what is being asked for in your message block:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
...
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

The solution proves that ssh needs to check the server to be a known host. If you have not assigned the needed known host, the gitlab server is not being trusted, which is meant by `the key_load_public cannot be found`. Yes, the error message is confusing.

You can also manually fill that ssh_config without the `echo` command, of course.

I have just seen that this was also the solution on Server Fault, see ["Permission denied (publickey)" with "key_load_public: No such file or directory" upon SSH attempt](https://serverfault.com/a/822962/607547).